# CodeIgniter validation always returns false on matches action

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, match

I've used CodeIgniter 3.1.0 in my current project. For form validation everything works well, but I have a problem when I want to use `matches` as a rule. This is my HTML:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm" id="confirm">
```

And this is my controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','matches[confirm]');
if ($this->input->post('password') != '' && $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    echo 'Error';
}
```

And I always get Error as the result even when I put the same value in both fields. What is my mistake?

Comment: Use `$this->load->library('form_validation');` in your constructor if you have not defined.

Comment: I do not see `$this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm','Confirm','required');`

Comment: @Virb I did it in my code. I have several validations in this file but I have problem only with what is described above

Comment: What about your form_open using form helper or form tags have you set all that correct

Comment: @wolfgang1983 updating password is not a required action in that page.

Comment: As I said in my question, everything work well and I have problem only with `matches` rule.

Answer (score 2):

Under the if condition it is mention ($this->input->post('password') != ''). So whatever value you insert it will execute true.

```
if ($this->input->post('password') != '' && $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        echo 'Error';
    }
```

I would suggest you as this

```
public function index()
{
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|matches[passconf]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
$this->load->view('myform');
}
else
{
$this->load->view('formsuccess');
}
}
```

as mention in http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html

Answer (score 2):

You must need to validate the other field as well when you trying to match, here is the code it will help you.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm', 'confirm', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
     echo 'ERROR';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful if it works.

If you have problem with your `matches`. Do one thing that create a function like `matches_pass` and use like below:

```
$this>form_validation>set_rules("input[password]","Password",'required|matches_pass[input---conf_password]');
```

and your function,

```
public function matches_pass($str, $field)
{
    $field = explode('---',$field);
    if ( ! isset($theField = $_POST [$field[0] ][ $field[1] ]))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }  
    return ($str !== $theField) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

And put it in your library.

Comment: Why do I need to use such code when the framework built it in itself?

Comment: Somehow, at some point there is no way CI core input can solve that. But I am checking why this is happening.